# Start pairing with the code (Zwave)

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, z-wave

I am developping a PoC Zwave using the project "Zwave Adapter Headless Host" and the program provided [here](https://www.hackster.io/dotMorten/discovering-and-interacting-with-any-alljoyn-device-0dbd86?ref=platform&ref_id=4087_updated___&offset=14)

But trying this program, I have one problem and one question:
-When I remove my Zwave dongle, there is no change in the properties I see. Is it a normal behaviour?
-In my program, I would like to start pairing my dongle to another device by the code. Is it a possible thing?
Thank you

Comment: Don't you need to press the power button in order to pair the Z-Wave device?

Comment: That's precisely what I don't want to do. In a previous version of my project I just had to push tje button "pair" in my soft and push the buttons on my sensor. I would like to keep this function.

Comment: I see. Maybe you can check this sample project, https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AllJoyn/Samples/ZWaveAdapter. https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/AllJoyn/Samples/ZWaveAdapter/open-zwave/cpp/src/Driver.cpp seems to support "Add Device" command.

Comment: Not sure if that's the right direction to go, I'll come back when I figure it out.

Comment: Found it, the OpenZWave wiki page https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave/wiki/Adding-Security-Devices-to-OZW https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave/wiki/Adding-Security-Devices-to-OZW says Manager::Get()->BeginControllerCommand(homeId, Driver::ControllerCommand_AddDevice,
callbackfn, context, true));

Comment: I'll try and tell you how it works

Comment: I tried to add the openZwave project to my sample project but I can't call any OpenZwave function as my project is a c# one. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I see. It is written in native c++ code. You need to have a C++/CLI layer. Try creating an windows runtime component project in C++, and see if it can be referenced by C# project.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: I'm working on it. I have an error when compiling OpenZwave as a runtime component :   xsd.exe stopped with the code 1

Comment: There's an Platform component project for your reference https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AllJoyn/Samples/ZWaveAdapter/AdapterLib. You can directly use it in your C# project.

Comment: This component is already included in my project but I still have to add OpenZwave to be able to use 'Manager::Get()->BeginControllerCommand(homeId, Driver::ControllerCommand_AddDevice, callbackfn, context, true))'     no?   In Addition, I'm not sure if this method is doing what I want now... I think i'll have the node ID for example to be able to add my node. The use I want is pushing button in the app, pushing the pairing button of the sensor ==> paired

Comment: There's void ZWaveAdapter::AddDevice(const uint32 homeId, const uint8 nodeId, bool bPending) and void ZWaveAdapter::RemoveDevice(const uint32 homeId, const uint8 nodeId, bool bMoveToPending) from ZWaveAdapter.cpp from AdapterLib, not sure if those do the same trick though.

Comment: I have the same problem, AdapterLib is a C++ project so I can't call it directly... The error I am having now is : WinRT doesn't support  #using for managed assembly. I'm looking more into it

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2nd question :

Executing the function [addNode(uint32 const _homeId, bool _doSecurity)](https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave/blob/master/cpp/src/Manager.cpp) make the Z-Wave controller to enter inclusion mode. Once you execute this function, you need to activate inclusion mode (physically) with your module (zwave light/sensor/...).
In other word, you can enter your z-Wave controller into inclusion mode using code and function, however, you need to physically press button on your other z-wave module to make them enter inclusion mode.

Bonus : To remove a module from your z-wave network, use the following function : removeNode(uint32 const _homeId)